# How to convert jQuery each() function to a single function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that iterate through each selector. However, I only have one selector now so I want to make it singular and I am not sure how.

Below is my code.

```
$.each($('[data-behaviour~=datepicker]'), function(index, element) {
  if (element.value) {
    var dsplit = element.value.split("-");
    var d =new Date(dsplit[0],dsplit[1]-1,dsplit[2]);
    element.value = d;
  }
  new Pikaday({ field: element });
});
```

Comment: what do u mean by "I have one selector"?

Comment: You only have one selector, but the selector you show could match multiple elements...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var value =  $('[data-behaviour~=datepicker]').val();
var dsplit = value.split("-");
var d =new Date(dsplit[0],dsplit[1]-1,dsplit[2]);
$('[data-behaviour~=datepicker]').val(d);

// I don't know what this is
//new Pikaday({ field: element });
// but I think:
new Pikaday({ field: $('[data-behaviour~=datepicker]') });
```